# The original language version of China Strike Force (2000)

Tags: dialogue, alternate-version, china-strike-force

According to the [IMDB page of *China Strike Force*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0266408/reference) (2000), the language of the movie is 
Mandarin & English. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Strike_Force) however calls the language as Cantonese & English (dubbed) but says that the movie "was shot in both Cantonese and English" so this implies that there are two versions of the same movie.

[Yesasia](https://www.yesasia.com/global/china-strike-force/1001810514-0-0-0-en/info.html) sells a Cantonese audio version and I personally have an official English version at home. Now the question is: what is the 'correct' version? I doubt that the English one is dubbed because a) the mouths of the actor and the dialogues correspond with each other and b) the movie stars several American actors like Coolio and Mark Dacascos.

Does this mean that there really are two different audio-versions of the same movie but that they are filmed separately?